# Problem with Oncreate view of bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation bar with 4 fragments and 1 activity inside another activity(in which all fragment will be displayed). I want my first fragment to be displayed on the starting of the activity(in which all fragment will be displayed) along with the matching item of bottom navigation bar. My fragment 1 is getting displayed on starting but with wrong item of the bottom navigation bar.
[image: fragment 1 with its matching item]

[image: fragment 2 with its matching item in bottom navigation view]
[image: This is what, I am getting on starting. Selected item should be Home(middle)]

This is what, I am getting on starting. Selected item should be Home(middle)

I have this under OnCreate

```
        btmNav = findViewById(R.id.btmnav);
            btmNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((navListner));
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new RecViewFragment()).commit();
```

and this outside Oncreate

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListner = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.navprofile:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.fragment_container,new Fragment2()).commit();
            break;
            case R.id.navmap:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivityBuses.this, MapActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.navhome:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.fragment_container,new Fragment2()).commit();
            break;
            case R.id.navmybus:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.fragment_container,new Fragment3()).commit();
            break;
            case R.id.navinfo:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.fragment_container,new Fragment4()).commit();
            break;
            }
            return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer,
just need to add this

```
btmNav.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navhome).setChecked(true);
```

below this

```
btmNav = findViewById(R.id.btmnav);
        btmNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener((navListner));
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new RecViewFragment()).commit();
```